# How to resize svg used in img tag in html?

Tags: html, svg

Today, I have started to learn SVG and using it in HTML.

So, I created a file in SVG as follows:

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewbox="0 0 400 200">
        <path d = "M0,100 L100,100 L125,50 L175,150 L225,50 L275,150 L300,100 L400,100"
                style="
                    stroke: #000000;
                    stroke-width: 5;
                    fill: none;
                    " 
        />
    </svg>
```

Then I tried to use it in html as image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        .....
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#"><img src="svg/mysvg.svg" height="48" width="48"></img></a></li>
                <li ...... />
                <li ...... />
                <li ...... />
            </ul>
        </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

But I cannot see the svg as its not resized. What is my mistake? Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Change `viewbox` to `viewBox` and see if that helps.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Yes that works like a charm.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage please turn your answer into an answer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `viewBox` has been written with a lower-case `b`. As a result, this parameter is not recognized by the browser. In an SVG without a `viewBox` attribute, all lengths are assumed to be in pixels, so resizing the SVG will have no effect.

If you change `viewbox` to `viewBox`, the SVG will scale so that the view box area matches the dimensions of the SVG (in much the same way as an ordinary embedded image).

Comment: in my case viweBox was fine, i have to remove width and height property in the svg tag